# 3.5mm to USB with a flash drive

Tags: usb, 3.5mm

I need to convert a 3.5mm aux input to USB, but it also needs to work as a flash drive. What are my possibilities, is there anything like that available for sale or do I need to make a custom PCB? I'm a total beginner in this matter and do not know where else to ask. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this should help: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=3.5%20mm%20jack%20to%20usb

Comment: What do you mean - you have a 3.5mm jack you want to plug in via USB, or you have a 3.5mm socket that you want to use as a USB port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want are three devices:

- A sampler or an audio card with a line-in (USB based)
- An USB pen drive
- An USB hub

I see no technical reason why you cannot build all three devices on a single PCB, but unless you are building many of them it might be cheaper to just pick a box and buy those three components.

Comment: I never thought of using a USB hub and converting those 2 basically into a single USB input. That's actually quite clever, thanks for the quick answer.